# Where could we get CIS Hardening Scripts for AWS EC2?

Tags: operating-systems, hardening, aws, cis-framework

CIS has published hardening standards for all operating systems of EC2 in AWS.

CIS also provides hardened images as well but they're quite expensive at $130/year/instance.

Is there a place where we can get open source hardening scripts to harden EC2 to meet CIS standards?

I am looking for scripts for all operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place you can find open source hardening scripts is [Github](https://github.com/search?q=cis%20hardening).

I recommend writing your own to ensure you understand exactly what is changing in the environment so if you have to troubleshoot an issue you'll have a sense of where to look and you can tailor hardening to meet your needs.